# If I write a placement new?How should I write normal operator delete?

Tags: c++, new-operator, delete-operator, placement-new

In "Effective C++" Item 52:Write placement delete if you write placement new.

Meyers says that for `Widget *pw = new (std::cerr) Widget;`, placement new will be invoked. But if placement new doesn't throw exception, and we get to a delete in client code: `delete pw;`. Then, this `delete` will only invoke the normal delete, not the placement delete.

Meyers then comes to the conclusion that you must provide the normal operator delete. So, what should this normal operator delete looks like? I think the inside of this normal operator delete should resemble the placement delete.

But if I use a normal operator new instead of placement new to create an object `Widget *pw = new Widget;`, and use `delete pw` afterwards, then it will also call the normal operator delete I wrote for placement new. But this does not seems to be right.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this in the first place, but if you do, just let the custom `operator delete` call the ordinary one. Note: the code can compile but misbehave (memory leak) if you don't provide an `operator delete` with arguments corresponding to the `operator new`.

Comment: You mean I shouldn't do this:"normal operator delete should resemble the placement delete" ?@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: Not sure what you mean, sorry.

Comment: I mean what do you think I shouldn't be doing in the first place.Can you say it in detail?@Cheersandhth.-Alf

Comment: oh. you shouldn't be doing low level allocator stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
struct Widget {
    Widget() { throw std::runtime_error(""); }

    // custom placement new
    static void* operator new(std::size_t sz, const std::string& msg) {
        std::cout << "custom placement new called, msg = " << msg << '\n';
        return ::operator new(sz);
    }

    // custom placement delete
    static void operator delete(void* ptr, const std::string& msg)
    {
        std::cout << "custom placement delete called, msg = " << msg << '\n';
        ::operator delete(ptr);
    }
};
int main() 
{
    try {
        Widget* p1 = new ("widget") Widget;
    } 
    catch(const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << '\n'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: But I think this is not what Meyers want to do.He doesn't want to use `try catch`.And what if I use `Widget* p1 = new Widget;`I want to know what normal operator delete will be like in this case@Andreas DM

Comment: Firstly,the placement new and delete will hide the global operator new and delete,this may cause error.I'm sure of it.Secondly,I want to know the implementation of normal operator delete,but Andreas didn't provide.These are the 2 reasons why I say this.@TonyD

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write a normal operator delete that resembles the placement delete.

Instead, when you want to delete an object created by placement new,you have to call placement delete through `Widget::delete(pw, std::cerr)`.You shouldn't call `delete pw` directly,if you do it this way, the compiler will complain.In vs2013, the compiler will output

> cannot delete pointers to objects of this type; the class has no non-placement overload for 'operator delete'

So,no need to worry about placement delete in normal operator delete.